# How to create a link that can't be shared?

Tags: http, cookies, cgi

We have a form in a website in which a visitor must submit their email address.
Then we send an email to that address with a download link.
The idea is prevent people from sharing the link and instead require them to enter their email addresses.

What I can think of is setting a cookie when the user submits the form and checking for that cookie when processing the download link.
This has 2 downsides, the same user won't be able to download the same file from different devices, and given the case a user chooses to delete their cookies, they won't be able to download the file anymore.
Any better solution? (that doesn't require the visitor to use any login or password)

Notes:
I really think it's a lousy marketing strategy but it's a request from a client.
That people create free email accounts only to get the file, or that they can share the file itself is outside of the scope of this task, so basically we don't care about that posibilites, because we can't do anything about that.

Answer (score 1):

In such situation I would send user link with mail itself or some generated token as GET parameter (e.g. http://my-site.com/download?mail=a@a.a). Then user opens mail and most likely visits this link before sharing it. Thus we can save HTTP's 'Referer' header, and require exactly same 'Referer' for all further visits. Because 'Referer' is same per mail provider (for example, Gmail opens link like http://google.com?q=http://a.com, which then opens http://a.com and 'Referer' will be constantly equal 'http://google.com?q=http://a.com', and because of such mechanism this is true for Gmail/Inbox native apps too), and for most providers is same even on different devices.

There are 4 problems:

1. User can open link only from his mail.
2. If user copies link to clipboard and then pastes it in new empty tab, 'Referer' will be empty, and sharing is still easy.
3. It is possible to copy link like http://google.com?q=http://a.com and sharing is still possible, however becomes a little tricky for average user.
4. Some services may give you different 'Referer' on different devices/browsers.

You can fix 4th problem by adding filtering and categorising User-agents. For example, assume average user has no more than 1 Mac, 1 Win PC, 1 Linux PC, 1 iPhone, 1 Android. On these devices he has different browsers, so we have to distinct OS X Safari, OS X Chrome, OS X Firefox, Win Safari, Win Chrome, Win Firefox etc. And if you get request with inappropriate 'Referer', but with User-agent that is from unfilled category, consider it as legit request.

Now 4th problem is fixed and 2 users having same OS-browser-family can't share link. However, problems:

1. It becomes easier to share link using different OS-browser-families.
2. It prohibits same user to open link on both of his iPads.
3. It prohibits same user to open link on guest device (only if your service should support this).